# Reading first bytes of a stream and putting them back again for other consumers?

Tags: c#, file-upload, stream, asp.net-core-webapi

One of my ASP.Net Core WebAPI actions receives a file as the body of the request. I want to directly stream it to a blob storage after having made some checks like checking the magic bytes. However reading the first bytes of the stream would remove them from the stream to my understanding, making them unavailable for streaming them to the blob storage. How to best handle that?

```
// 1. Check magic bytes of the file sent in the stream
// The issue I have here: I want to pass on the stream to another method (see step 2),
// but if I read the first bytes here, then the stream that will be available to
// step 2 will be missing the first bytes!
// -> How can I solve this?

// 2. Upload file to blob storage            
UploadFileToBlobStorage(stream);
```

Comment: Do you need to continue reading the stream if the magic bytes don’t match?

Comment: no, in that case I would return an error and cancel further processing.

Comment: You could create a simple wrapper Stream for the file's stream, forward most method calls to it, and if the first few bytes are not the magic ones, throw an exception.  It's potentially a little messy in the sense that you would be starting the blob-storage process, but it's likely that an exception thrown in very rare cases is fine there, and the storage service would never see the first chunk anyway.